# Data in 2 text files - unable to write variable to output file

Tags: powershell, variables

My post has previously been marked as a duplicate but the compare-object thread I was pointed at didn't help me to resolve the issue I'm having. Does anyone know how I resolve this issue? Thanks

I've written a little script to compare text in 'file 1' with the text in 'file 2'.

If the text in 'file 1' exists in 'file 2', 'Entry exists' is displayed on the screen.

If the text in 'file 1' doesn't exist in 'file 2', 'Doesn't exist' is appended to 'file 2'.

This works but really what I'd like to be able to do is rather than append 'Doesn't exist' to 'file 2', I'd like to append the value that doesn't exist in 'file 2' to the end of 'file 2'. Whenever I try this, I get a blank line appended to 'file 2'.

Here's the script:

```
$InputFile = "d:\temp\Input.txt"
$Input = Get-Content $InputFile
$AppendFile = "d:\temp\appendfile.txt"
foreach ($line in $Input)  {
                if ($line = Select-String -AllMatches ^$line$ -path $AppendFile) {
                                Write-Host "Entry exists"}
                               else {
                                Write-output "$line" | out-file -width 300 -append $AppendFile
                                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated solution (common aliases used):

```
write "A`nB" | sc append.txt
write "A`nB`nC" | sc input.txt
$append = (gc append.txt); 
(gc input.txt) | 
 %{ 
   $inputLine = $_; 
   if(-not ($append | ?{ $_ -like  $inputLine })) { 
     Add-Content -Path append.txt -Value $inputLine 
   } 
  }; 
gc append.txt # displays 'A`nB`nC'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The input file has the following 3 letters in it, A B C and they are on 3 separate lines. The append file only has A B on 2 separate lines. With this example the script should recognise C is missing from the append file and add it onto a separate line but all I get is a blank line. I get the feeling it's reading $line from the append file which is blank. How can I reference $line from the input file please. Any ideas ?

Comment: @silkman Hope the question is still actual. Here is the updated solution for the example you gave. `get-content input.txt` gets the content line by line (otherwise with `-raw` switch) so you can reference it this way. Hope it helps!